# Navigation Controller and Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode11

Very stuck on an issue
I have a tab bar controller within a navigation controller
The first tab has a calendar on it (which is basically a collection view)
I am trying to make a rightbarbuttonitem to scroll to todays date

I can only seem to create the button within the tabbarcontroller
The function that I call then calls one in the CalendarViewController
but it doesn't seem to work

What is the correct way to implement a bar button item within a tabbarcontroller?

In the tabbarcontroller I have...

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .bookmarks, target: self, action: #selector(goToToday))

@objc func goToToday() {
    print("pressed")
    CalendarViewController().goToToday()
}
```

In the CalendarViewController I have...

```
 @objc func goToToday(_ animate: Bool = true) {
    print("tapped")
    calendarView.scrollToDate(Date(),animateScroll: animate)
    calendarView.selectDates([Date()])
    title = "Test"
}
```

The function works if I call it from a button in CalendarViewController. And I get both print commands when called from the navigation controller but that's all

Comment: `goToToday` creates a new VC, calls a method on it and then discards it.

Comment: Ah I see. So if I define tabOne as the CalendarViewController, I could then call the functions directly?

Comment: Something like...
    @objc func goToToday() {
        tabOne?.calendarView.scrollToDate(Date())
        tabOne?.calendarView.selectDates([Date()])
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `gotToToday` on the instance you're using as the first tab and not on a new instance as you've done here. Here's what you need to do in `gotToToday` in TabBarController:

```
@objc func goToToday() {
    print("pressed")
    if let calendarViewController = viewControllers[0] as? CalendarViewController {
        calendarViewController.goToToday()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. 
I see what I did wrong now. Follow up question. Can I remove or hide the rightbarbuttonitem when I'm on other tabs?

Comment: Hiding bar button item seems unrelated to this question. Why don't post another question  with details and share the link here, I'll take a look and help you out.